# Python - Get percentage of minority class in a list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list, how can I write an elegant one-liner to calculate the percentage of the minority class in a list?

For example, for `list1 = [1,1,1,-1,-1]`, the minority class is `-1`. The percentage of `-1` in the list will be `2/5=0.4`

For another list `list2 = [1,-1,-1,-1,-1]`, the minority class is `1`. The percentage of `1` in the list will be `1/5=0.2`

Comment: What happens if there are 2 "minorities"?

Comment: If there are more than 1 minorities, the percentages for those minorities  would be same so it does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

```
import collections

list1 = [1,1,1,-1,-1]
p = min(collections.Counter(list1).values())*1.0/len(list1)
print(p)
# Output
0.4
```

---

`collections.Counter(list1)` returns a dict with the *key:value* pair `element:frequency`. In this case, it will be `Counter({1: 3, -1: 2})`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

nums = [1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
# if using Python 2 use float(len(nums))
print(Counter(nums).most_common()[-1][-1] / len(nums))
>> 0.2
```

`Counter.most_common()` returns a list of tuples of the form `(element, count)` ordered from most to least common, so `most_common()[-1][-1]` returns the element that is the least common.

If there are several minorities, one of them will be chosen arbitrarily for the calculation. For example, using my code with `nums = [3, 3, -1, 1, 2]` will also return `0.2`, using either `-1`, `1`or `2` for the calculation.

Comment: `Counter(nums).most_common()[-1][-1] / len(nums)` equals `0`.  Convert numerator or denominator into `float`.

Comment: @sparkandshine See the comment in my code regarding using Python 2

Comment: Both numerator and denominator are `int`, therefore the fraction is `0`.

Comment: @sparkandshine, it doesn't matter. You can convert either one to float: `print 1 / float(5) >>0.2`

Comment: thx, now I see the difference of dividing two integers in python2 and 3.